# DisplayPort shows no signal after Ubuntu 16.04 minimal install on ZBox Zotac CI323

Tags: 16.04, intel-graphics, displayport

I have have a ZOTAC CI323-nano PC which has 1 displayport, 1 HDMI and 1 VGA.

If I connect 2 monitors - 1 to the HDMI port and 1 to the VGA port they mirror each other with a Ubuntu 16.04 minimal installation.  This is good though I dont want to use VGA.

If i connect the DisplayPort and HDMI to monitors i get blank monitors. If i powercycle I see POST on both screens and then they go blank.

I tried a fresh install with only the DisplayPort connect and the install process completed through a monitor connected via DisplayPort but when it rebooted to load the OS it went black.

Whilst minimal Ubuntu is install i have been installing the following packages
apt install xserver-xorg-video-intel
apt install xorg openbox

The desired result here is that I have two monitors connected - 1 to HDMI the other to DisplayPort and they mirror each other like the HDMI and VGA currently do.

I have been given a possible workaround of setting video frequency from 60Hz to 30Hz. I'm not sure I like this, also not sure how I would go about doing that.

Comment: https://www.zotac.com/us/product/mini_pcs/zbox-ci323-nano is the PC which has a Intel Braswell chipset